# Mysql: Row size too large

Tags: mysql

Всем привет!

У меня есть таблица `temp`. В ней:

- 6 полей `int`
- 1 поле `tinyint`
- 2 поля `varchar` (300 и 100)
- 15 полей `text`

Однажды при попытке Updat'а строки получил:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum
>   row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You
>   have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs.

Гуглил - но везде пишут убирайте `varchar` и меняйте на `text`. Я поменял - не помогло. Хотелось бы обойтись без изменения настроек InnoDB и компрессии таблицы, если это возможно.

Comment: [говорят нельзя без смены fileformat](http://serverfault.com/a/326870) т.к. в обычном виде text/blob все равно держит первые 768 байт в таблице

Ну и без баракуды держать text/blob в  таблице весьма сомнительная идея.

Comment: Спасибо за отличную ссылку! Можешь написать это как ответ - я поставлю +1 и затем приму - если не будет решений лучше.

Comment: зачем нужны 15 полей text? вынести их в отдельную таблицу id, textfield_id, text... представляю себе трафик - при каждом апдейте все 15 полей перезаписываются.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov почему вы считаете что перезаписываются ? по крайней мере в barracuda не должно быть такого.

Comment: @eicto, ну если идет редактирование целой записи, то все поля и будут писаться, не думаю что при такой таблице (не слишком хорошей структуры) идет анализ что изменилось, а что нет. типа ок нажали и пошел update полного списка полей. домыслы, понятно дело.

Comment: да, update у всех полей.
но он в этой таблице случается 1 раз в 7 дней.
по прогнозам при самом благоприятном развитии проекта в этой таблице update будет 1 раз в день. Чаще не будет 100%!
Поэтому и выносить смысла нет.

Comment: Эта таблица в основном для select'a, а select при выборке из 1  таблицы работает быстрее, чем select еще и со 2ой таблицей.

Comment: @kezman - сомнительное утверждение в вашем случае.

Answer (score 1):

Эту проблему можно решить путем изменения значения innodb_log_file_size в my.ini конфигурационном файле.

Например

```
[mysqld]
....
#это у меня по умолчанию стоит
innodb_log_file_size = 5M 
#5M Можно заменить на 25М или 250M
#Дальше говорится как определиться на сколько 
....
```

Как я понял ошибка происходит из за того что innodb_log_file_size слишком мал чем размер строки с ошибкой.[Источник1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637733/mysql-error-code-1118-row-size-too-large-8126-changing-some-columns-to-te)

**InnoDB Notes [Источник2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163614/error-1118-42000-row-size-too-large):**

Убедитесь, что настройка innodb_log_file_size достаточно велико -- innodb_log_file_size должен быть установлен на значение больше, ***чем в 10 раз чем размер BLOB данных***, найденных в строках таблиц плюс длина других полей переменной длины (VARCHAR, VARBINARY и поля типа TEXT).
Несоблюдение этого правила может привести к "Row size too large" ошибкетекст, выделенный жирным шрифтом.